# Changing a function that calculates XIRR to return NA instead of stopping in R

Tags: r, function, finance

I am using an XIRR function to calculate the XIRR of several different data frames. All data frames have 2 columns, date and cash flows. For some data frames, the XIRR function returns a value, for others, the functions simply stops and throws an error. Here is a link to the function:

https://github.com/SunilVeeravalli/XIRR_in_R/blob/master/Xirr%20Code.R

The function is:

```
library(tidyverse)

xirr <- function(dataset) {
  
  # creating a function to calculate npv value
  npv <- function(range, dataset){
    for(test.rate in range) {
      
      max.date <- max(dataset$dates)
      
      temp <- dataset %>%
        mutate(npv = amount * ((1 + test.rate/100)^(as.numeric(max.date - dates)/365))) %>%
        select(npv) %>%
        .[1]
      if(sum(dataset$amount) > 0) {
        if(sum(temp) > 0) {
          min.rate <- test.rate
          next
        } else {
          max.rate <- test.rate
          break
        }
      } else {
        if(sum(temp) < 0) {
          min.rate <- test.rate
          next
        } else {
          max.rate <- test.rate
          break
        }
      }
    }
    return(list(min.rate = min.rate, max.rate = max.rate))
  }
  
  
  names(dataset) <- c("dates", "amount")
  
  max.rate <- c()
  min.rate <- c()
  
  if(sum(dataset$amount) > 0) {
    
    range <- seq(from = 0, to = 10000, by = 100)    
    hundreds <- npv(range, dataset)
    
    range <- seq(from = hundreds$min.rate, to = hundreds$max.rate, by = 10)
    tens <- npv(range, dataset)
    
    range <- seq(from = tens$min.rate, to = tens$max.rate, by = 1)
    ones <- npv(range, dataset)
    
    range <- seq(from = ones$min.rate, to = ones$max.rate, by = 0.01)
    decimals <- npv(range, dataset)
    
    return(paste("XIRR is ", mean(unlist(decimals)), "%", sep = ""))   
    
  } else {
    
    range <- seq(from = 0, to = -10000, by = -100)
    hundreds <- npv(range, dataset)
    
    range <- seq(from = hundreds$min.rate, to = hundreds$max.rate, by = -10)
    tens <- npv(range, dataset)
    
    range <- seq(from = tens$min.rate, to = tens$max.rate, by = -1)
    ones <- npv(range, dataset)
    
    range <- seq(from = ones$min.rate, to = ones$max.rate, by = -0.01)
    decimals <- npv(range, dataset)
    
    return(paste("XIRR is ", mean(unlist(decimals)), "%", sep = "")) 
  }
}
```

The two test data frames are:

```
mydate <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2015-01-01"), to = as.Date("2015-12-01"),
                   by = "month")
cashflow1 <- c(-50000, 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 300, 400, 440, 0)
testdf1 <- cbind.data.frame(mydate, cashflow1)

cashflow2 <- c(451266, rep(0, times = 11))
testdf2 <- cbind.data.frame(mydate, cashflow2)
```

```
xirr(testdf1)
xirr(testdf2)
```

As you can see, running the xirr for testdf2 results in an error "Error in seq.default(from = hundreds$min.rate, to = hundreds$max.rate,  :
'from' must be of length 1 "

Instead of this function throwing an error, I want to modify it in such a way that it returns NA instead of giving an error.

Comment: Also consider this, I am not familiar enough on this function to be sure if this is doing the same as you try to achieve. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tvm/versions/0.5.0/topics/xirr

Comment: The xirr function from the tvm package suffers from the same problem: It throws an error when I run it on certain test scenarios. I want it to return NA for some fringe cases (added in the edited post).

Comment: Ok according to some general definitions given for Excel "XIRR expects at least one positive cash flow and one negative cash flow; otherwise, XIRR returns the #NUM! error value." So what you can do is add a step to check that prior to any other steps in your function to calculate the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XIRR can only be calculated when at least 1 value is below zero and at least 1 value is above zero (according to Excel definitions: "XIRR expects at least one positive cash flow and one negative cash flow; otherwise, XIRR returns the #NUM! error value." https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xirr-function-de1242ec-6477-445b-b11b-a303ad9adc9d

So what we can do is check your data first and then either return NA right away or do your calculations. Either youw own code or use the xirr function from the tvm package.

```
xirr <- function(dataset) {
  if(min(dataset$cashflow) < 0 & max(dataset$cashflow) > 0) {
    # do your stuff (your function OR tvm::xirr)
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}
```